# Using Traverse from to project the records in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm using the Vehicle History database with *OrientDb Studio 2.2.8*, and I want to project all of the records of the `automobile` class that are made by `Kia`.

The schema for the database looks like this:

`(Automobile) --isModel--> (Model) --isMake--> (Make)`

where `Automobile`, `Model`, and `Make` are vertices and `isModel`, and `isMake` are edge types.

I want to use a **traverse statement** to return an equivalent result set as I get from this command:

`Select expand(in('isMake').in('isModel')) from Make where name = "Kia"`

whose result is...

```
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|#   |@RID    |@CLASS   |color    |convertib|out_isMod|trailerHi|emissions|safety   |out_Purch|VIN      |
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|0   |#17:1441|Automo...|White    |true     |[#24:1...|false    |2016-0...|2014-0...|[#23:5...|840CDC...|
|1   |#17:1576|Automo...|Maroon   |true     |[#24:1...|false    |2010-0...|2004-0...|[#23:5...|E71761...|
|2   |#17:1503|Automo...|Dark Gray|true     |[#24:1...|false    |2009-0...|2016-1...|[#23:5...|FAEB6F...|
+----+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I tried running this:

```
Select
  from (traverse in from Make while $depth <= 2)
  where name = "Kia"
```

I just get one record returned, and it's not of the Automobile class like I expected it to be. It is from Make.

```
+----+-------+------+----+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|#   |@RID   |@CLASS|name|in_isMake                            |out_Sold                    |
+----+-------+------+----+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|0   |#15:612|Make  |Kia |[#25:1767,#25:2036,#25:2067,#25:2131]|[#22:5153,#22:5383,#22:5655]|
+----+-------+------+----+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Basically, I want to use a Traverse starting from `Make` to project the three Kia automobiles in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT FROM (TRAVERSE in() 
FROM (SELECT FROM Make where name='Kia')) 
WHERE @class='Automobile'
```